# Laravel Pivot table eloquent relationships

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5, relationships

**Situation:** In my *laravel project*. Below are the *4 Tables*. `movie_venue` is a *pivot table* of *movies* and *venues*. I need to access the showtimes using movie model.

```
$movie = $this->model->find($movie_id);

$venues = $movie->venues;
```

Using eloquent relations i can access the venues list. But cant able to create a relationship for getting showtimes from movie model.

```
| movies     | venues | movie_venue | showtimes     |
----------------------------------------------------|
| id         | id     | id          |id             |
| name       | name   | movie_id    |movie_venue_id |
| ....       |  ....  | venue_id    |time           |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using a One-to-many relationship for `Venues` to `Showtimes`?

You could try something like:

```
foreach ($movies->venues as $venue) {
    foreach ($venue->showtimes as $showtime) {
        //do something with your showtime.
    }
}
```

By the way: wouldn't it make more sense to start from the `venue` and than access `Showtimes`?

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, you can try something like this:

```
$movie = Movie::find($id);
$venues = $movie->venues;

foreach ($venues->showtimes as $showtime) {
    // Here you'll get the showtimes per venue.
}
```

Comment: I really use this for a mobile app as web service. When user request a movie by id. I need to send the movie details with nearest venues and the showtimes in each venue. The tables movies and venues have pivot table named movie_venue. Its primary key is the foreign key of showtimes table. So how can i create a relationship between movie to venue then to showtimes. Hope this make sense

Comment: Thank you for help